# Onelogin SAML Python toolkit - Logout

Tags: onelogin

I have recently started using the SAML Python toolkit (Flask) from OneLogin.  I have a problem in that when I sign out of the application itself, it does not sign out of SSO so that the application can be re-entered into with existing login credentials stored in SSO.  Is there anything that you can suggest I can look at to help solve the problem?  Logging into the application is no problem, just when logging out, SSO still retains the details.  Is there something in settings.json I need to do further?

I can force it to SSO to fully log out but only by force, it does not do it automatically.

What is the difference between singleLogoutService for the sp and singleLogoutService for the idp?

Any other aspects of the settings.json file that I can check over / alter?

Thank you in advance.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I've wrestled with the same problem myself. From what I learned, its possible to setup a logout functionality which you can then add to your settings.json. However, this requires SAML2 to be configured in a certain way in addition to that if I recall correctly.

The solution I came up with for now is to have a logout page which deletes the session data via "request.session.delete()". However, in order for this to work, the user then has to completely close his/her browser afterwards. Therefore, this command is perhaps best displayed on a webpage that says something like, "You have been logged out, please completely close your browser to properly end your session."